# border-style: ridge doesn' work on Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser, border

I've got this css to style the border of a table:

```
border-right-width: 3px;
border-bottom-width: 3px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-right-color: #558FA6;
border-bottom-color: #558FA6;
border-style: ridge;
```

It works fine in Firefox

[image]

but is ignored by Chrome:

[image]

I checked a similar answer, but does not work for me. Need a similar css code that works also in chrome.

Comment: This is how it looks like in chrome. Check this link in both browsers http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=ridge

Comment: just use border-right and for firefox use moz-borfer-right... that should work fine... atleast it did in my case

Comment: Gaurav, did, but i need a workaround to make a similar border in chrome. Weinde, that's not the same (or similar) effect